# Get form input from specific form by name [JS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a from that PHP builds with and jQuery and ajax retrieve to the current page. The problem now is that all of the input elements have the same names and Id's. The forms do  have unique ID's. How to I point to the unique form then to the input ID's that have duplicates?

All I need is something like `document.FormId.inputID.value()`
So that I can get data from specific forms as the inputs themselves share Ids

Here is the code that the  PHP uses:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $Output .= 
"<tr>".
'<form name="'.$row['EmailID'] .'"  action="" method="post">'.
"<td>" .
'<input name="Email" type="email" id = "Email" value="'.$row['Email'].'">'                      ."</td>"."<td>".
'<input name="FName" type="text" id = "FName" value="' . $row['FName'] .
'">' .
"</td>"."<td>" .
<input name="LName" type="text"  id = "LName" value="' . $row['LName'] .
'">' . "</td>".
//this hidden value passes the Email ID with the form
'<input id="EmailID" type="hidden" value="' . $row['EmailID'] . '" name="EmailID">'.

"<td>" .
'<input type="button" class="button" name = "Edit" id="Action" value = "Edit"  onclick="validateInput('.$row['EmailID'].')  />' 
. "</td>".
"<td>" 
. '<input type="button" class="button" name = "Delete"  id="Action"   value="Delete"
 onclick="validateInput('.$row['EmailID'].');" />'. "</td>".
"</form>".
"</tr>";
}   
echo $Output;
```

here is a form that it produces:

```
<tr>
<form name="21" action="" method="post">    <td><input name="Email" type="email" id="Email" value="samesc@yahoo.com"></td>
<td><input name="FName" type="text" d="FName" value=""></td>
<td><input name="LName" type="text" id="LName" value=""></td>
<input id="EmailID" type="hidden" value="21" name="EmailID">
<td><input type="button" class="button" 
name="Edit" id="Action" value="Edit" onclick="validateInput(21) /></td>
<td><input type=" button"=""></td>
</form>

</tr>
```

Now here is the old JS that would pull the values then later use them through ajax.
Right now this is broken and not working, but you can see how it *was* working.

```
function validateInput(RowId) { 


$(function() {
    $('.Action').click(function(event) {
        alert('Button ' + String(event.target.value) + ' was clicked!');
    });
});

var Action = document.getElementById("Action").value;
alert(Action);
if(Action == 'Delete'){
    var EmailID = document.getElementById("EmailID").value;
    var Email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
    alert("'Action == 'Delete'" + EmailID);


    $.ajax({
        url: "ProEmail.php",
        data: { Action: Action, EmailID: EmailID, Email:Email },
        type: "POST",
        success : function (data) {
            LoadTables();                       
        }
    });
    return null;
    }


var Fname = document.getElementById("FName").value;
var Lname = document.getElementById("LName").value;
```

Comment: `id`s MUST be unique, that is your first issue

Comment: @SamCreamer ... thank you but I did have it working just fine a different way with duplicut ids.  I do want to see it it will work by using the form names then the element Ids.

Comment: yes, you can make it work using names, classes, etc, but IDs should still be unique. EDIT: otherwise what's the point of an ID?

Comment: @SamCreamer Well yes and no, I do see your point. so should I just use names and leave Ids alone? The reason that I  started using Ids is that was the only wan that I knew how to call values with PHP and posting a form to the page. So now I'm reworking the page to make it better and cleaner.

Comment: Using duplicated `ID`s doesn't explicitly invalidate your HTML, but will almost certainly cause a lot of problems if you ever want to refer to them with javascript (which you do).

Comment: @SamCreamer, I see. I just was treating it like a 3d array with the forms and inputs.

Comment: I see, in that case, maybe use classes.

Comment: I will look in to that. But how does that work with in JS and retrieving the values? `document.getElementsByClassName()` but what do I use to select the form class that will be a number, then the form elements in side the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your form has a name attribute, you can access the particular form using javascript by using document.formName. In your case document.21 should work.

Comment: Thankyou, Ill give that a shot.
`document.forms[formName].elements["InputID"].value; ` would that be it?

Comment: `Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined ` on  this line `var test = document.forms[RowId].elements[FName].value;`

Comment: This should be a working example in your case: document.forms[0].elements['FName'].value. The quotes are important

Comment: Use document.forms[0] to reference your first form and subsequent numbers for subsequent forms. rowId wont work as a good reference because it's a number and you're dealing with arrays and collections. Sorry if this is confusing or not helping you but I have tested this and it works for me.

Comment: So I would need to add reference numbers for the input IDs anyway wouldn't I?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56137/discussion-between-whiteshadow-and-woleo).

Comment: Yes or instead of using the rowId you can implement a counter in your PHP file and make the name attributes something like form0, form1, form2 etc.